# Reading each line from a text file, word by word and converting to int (Infinite loop or crashing?)

Tags: c++, while-loop, strtok, strdup

I'm trying to read in this text file:

```
8 4 4 6 1
8 4 4 6 2
8 4 4 6 3
8 4 4 6 4
8 4 4 6 5
8 4 4 6 6
8 4 4 6 7
8 4 4 6 8
11 4 4 6 3
15 11 13
7 2 1 4 4 
9 4 3 9 9
8 2 1 5 4 
10 1 2 3 4 6 1
6 1 1 2 5 3 2
13 1 1 2 10 3 8 
11 2 11 10 7
```

And printing it exactly as shown to the console (to make sure I got every input).

However, for some reason my code crashes after reading in the first line. I can't even terminate the debugger.

Here's my code:

```
while(getline(inFile, buffer)){
    buffer2 = strdup(buffer.c_str());
    line = strtok(buffer2, " ");
    size = atoi(line);
    cout << size << " ";

    while(line!=NULL){
        line = strtok(NULL, " ");
        cout << line << " ";
    }

    cout << "~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to  contain [mcve]

Comment: why are you calling all those `str_foo` when you just want to print the same you read?

Comment: what is this line supposed to achieve `line = strtok(NULL, " ");` ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, that is a correct way to use `strtok`. See the example code at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok.

Comment: @RSahu huh, C is weird sometimes :P

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, why blame C only? The landscape of libraries -- standard or not -- is littered with sentinel values.

Comment: After finding the last token in a line, the call to `strtok` will return a `NULL` pointer. `std::cout << line` won’t do anything good when that happens.

Comment: @RSahu, the question is, if you are using C++ why use `strtok()` for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use C++ you should take advantage of that, use string streams:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std; //for sample purposes, should not be used

int main() {

    int temp, count = 0, sum = 0, total = 0;
    string buffer;
    ifstream myFile("in.txt");
    if (!myFile.is_open())
        cout << "No file" << endl;
    else{
        while(getline(myFile, buffer)){
            sum = 0;
            stringstream ss(buffer);
            while(ss >> temp){
                count++;         //number count            
                sum += temp;     //line sum
                cout << temp << " ";
            }
            total += sum;   //total sum
            cout << endl << "count: " << count <<  endl
                << "sum: " << sum << endl << "total: " << total << endl << endl;
        }
    myFile.close();
    }
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~" << endl;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking the memory allocated by `strdup()`.  You need to call `free()` when you are done using `buffer2`.

But more importantly, `strtok()` returns `NULL` when there are no more tokens to return.  But it is *undefined behavior* to pass a `NULL` `char*` pointer to `operator<<`.  Your `while` loop is doing exactly that when it reaches the end of each line, so *anything* could happen, including crashing.

Try this instead:

```cpp
while (getline(inFile, buffer)) {
    buffer2 = strdup(buffer.c_str());
    if (buffer2 != NULL) {
        line = strtok(buffer2, " ");
        while (line != NULL) {
            size = atoi(line);
            cout << size << " ";
            line = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
        free(buffer2);
    }
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
}
```

That being said, why are you using `strdup()`, `strtok()`, and `atoi()` at all?  You are writing C++ code, you should C++ semantics instead of C semantics.  For example, you can use `std::istringstream` instead, eg:

```cpp
while (getline(inFile, buffer)) {
    istringstream iss(buffer);
    while (iss >> size) {
        cout << size << " ";
    }
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As always, there are many possible solutions. I would like to show an additional one. This is using more modern C++ elements, mainly from the algorithm and iterator library.

So, what will we do?

First we read each line as a `std::string` in a simple for loop with `std::getline`. Then we will put the line again in a `std::istringstream` so that we can take advantage of C++ iterator: `std::istream_iterator`.

This iterator will iterate over the elements in the string and extract all integers. It is like calling the extractor operator ( >> ) for all elements in the line string.

We use the iterator in the so called range constructor of os a `std::vector`. This inplace created vector, will be added to the destiantion data. So, as a result, we will get vector of vector of int: A 2-dimensional vector.

For debug purposes, we copy each row of intes to `std::cout`.

Please note that we do really need only very few and very simple statements to fulfill the task.

Please check.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

std::istringstream sourceFile{R"(8 4 4 6 1
8 4 4 6 2
8 4 4 6 3
8 4 4 6 4
8 4 4 6 5
8 4 4 6 6
8 4 4 6 7
8 4 4 6 8
11 4 4 6 3
15 11 13
7 2 1 4 4 
9 4 3 9 9
8 2 1 5 4 
10 1 2 3 4 6 1
6 1 1 2 5 3 2
13 1 1 2 10 3 8 
11 2 11 10 7)"};

int main()
{
    // Here we will store the resulting int values
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> data{};

    for (std::string line{}; std::getline(sourceFile, line); ) {

        // Split the line into integers and add to target array
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        data.emplace_back(std::vector<int>(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), {}));
    }       

    // Now all data is in our vector of vector of int

    // Show read data on screen
    std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const std::vector<int>& v){ 
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << "\n";});

    return 0;
}
```

Please note. I do not have files on SO. So I used a `std::istringstream` as input stream. You may of course exchange it with any other `std::ftream`